# What is wrong with this query (Select as RES1 Union Select where param IN (RES1)

Tags: mysql

The query:

SELECT ct_cid as level1 FROM cat_tree WHERE ct_sid=$sid_int AND ct_parent =$cid_int)
UNION (SELECT ct_cid as level2 FROM cat_tree WHERE ct_sid=$sid_int AND ct_parent IN level1)

The query is supposed to find the child nodes up to 2 levels of a tree node. 
I get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`level1`)" How can I use the results of the 1st select in the 2nd select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need parens around the second SELECT statement... Also, the field names and order must match in BOTH SQL-Select statements.  What you may want is something like

```
select 1 as LevelID, CT_CID from cat_tree where...  
UNION
select 2 as levelID, CT_CID from cat_tree where ...
```

Now, your other half of the question... using the results of the first...  Redo the query as a sub-select in the SECOND query...

```
select 1 as LevelID, CT_CID 
    from cat_tree
    where ct_sid = $sid_int
      and ct_parent = $cid_int
union
select 2 as LevelID, CT_CID
    from cat_tree
    where ct_sid = $sid_int
      and ct_parent IN
              ( select ct_cid  
                     from cat_tree
                     where ct_sid = $sid_int
                       and ct_parent in $cid_int )
```

Notice the parens are only needed in the SUB-SELECT, not the UNION select.  Not knowing your data, there might be an easier approach to what you are trying to get

Comment: works. note the buttom line should be ct_parent = $cid_int not t_parent in $cid_int

Answer (score 0):

This is not how SQL works. IN requires a list of values (or a subselect which creates the list).

Please post the table structure of the tables you are querying, along with explanations what the fields mean. Then maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but the structure you're after might be :

```
SELECT ct_cid as level2 FROM cat_tree WHERE ct_sid=$sid_int AND ct_parent IN 
(
   SELECT ct_cid as level1 FROM cat_tree WHERE ct_sid=$sid_int AND ct_parent =$cid_int) 
)
```

Comment: Won't work since I need it to return values from the first select and the 2nd select.